# ListBox doesn't show collection of objects in C#

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, listbox

**EDITED! WORKING CODE**

I have the following class:

```
class Medic
{
    private readonly int codM;
    private string numeM;
    private string specialitate;

    //i have a constructor and properties with get and set, correctly written
}
```

I added 3 textBoxes to the form to be filled, each one related to one of the class attributes.

After this i have a button, and if all 3 textbox fields are correctly completed, a new class object is created.

This object will be added to a List. And this list of objects I want to be displayed in a listBox, and be updated as I add new objects.

Also, I want to have 2 objects already in the List and displayed in the listBox as I run the program, created in the code I mean, not using the textBoxes, and the new entered objects to come after these. I barely know where to write the code to create these 2 objects, same as where is ok to create and populate the List of objects or to write the code to bind this list into the ListBox;

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
    {

        List<Medic> listaMedici = new List<Medic>();
        Medic m1 = new Medic(0, "ion", "endocrinologie");

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            listaMedici.Add(m1);


        }
private void button1_AddObject_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (textBox1_cod.Text == "")
        errorProvider1.SetError(textBox1_cod, "Introduceti codul medicului!");
    else if (textBox2_nume.Text == "")
        errorProvider1.SetError(textBox2_nume, "Introduceti numele medicului");
    else if (Regex.IsMatch(textBox2_nume.Text, @"^[ a-zA-Z]+$") == false)
        errorProvider1.SetError(textBox2_nume, "Numele contine doar litere si spatii");
    else if (textBox3_specialitate.Text == "")
        errorProvider1.SetError(textBox3_specialitate, "Introduceti specialitatea medicului");
    else
    {
        try
        {
            Medic medic = new Medic(Convert.ToInt32(textBox1_cod.Text), textBox2_nume.Text, textBox3_specialitate.Text);

            foreach (Medic m in listaMedici)
            {
                if (textBox1_cod.Text == m.CodM.ToString())
                {
                    throw new Exception("Codul contractului incalca proprietatea de unicitate. Introduceti un cod unic");
                    textBox1_cod.Clear();
                }
            }
                listaMedici.Add(medic);
                listBox1_medici.DataSource = new ObservableCollection<Medic>(listaMedici);
                listBox1_medici.DisplayMember = nameof(Medic.NumeM);
                listBox1_medici.ValueMember = nameof(Medic.CodM);
                listBox1_medici.SelectedIndex = 0;


            MessageBox.Show("ADDED!");

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            errorProvider1.Clear();
            textBox1_cod.Clear();
            textBox2_nume.Clear();
            textBox3_specialitate.Clear();
        }
    }

}

private void listBox1_medici_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
}
```

Comment: The display member should be the name of the property to display, not a string property. In your case it should be "NumeM"

Comment: You can also consider using ObjectListView.  http://objectlistview.sourceforge.net/cs/index.html

Comment: Look into `CollectionViewSource` and use `ItemsSource` instead of `DataSource`.

Comment: `listBox1_medici.DataSource = ...` indicates that it's a WinForms ListBox, not WPF. What exactly are you asking about?

Answer (score 0):

The display member should be the name of the property to display, not a string property. Reflection is used to look for a property of the name of the display member. For example if your `medic.NumeM` value is "Hello" WPF will look for a property named "Hello", retrieve the value of the property and display it in the listbox.

In your case the code should be: `listBox1_medici.DisplayMember = "NumeM";`